# Execute a block of code in the background

Tags: php, exec, background-process

I need to execute a block of code in the background. For that, i did made search in the web and got that `exec` is the function to do that. But i couldnt execute the script in the background. Dont know what is my mistake, Actually i m using

> $path ='/app/updates/new'; //this is my url containing the code
>
> exec('nohup php '.$path);

i do some DB operations in the code, but that didnt works. Dont know how to correct it. This is the first time i m using `exec()` for executing code in another block. Help me please, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this to execute your php script in background:

```
exec('php ' . $path . ' > /dev/null &');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but same result..:(

Comment: Maybe you have problem in your script?
What is the output of your script? Is there any error?

Comment: No.. the scrip is correct when i m executing the url directly..but can't execute using exec...

Comment: Did you try execute script from command line? I think that it can rely on something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and have problem here...

Comment: That's it. Your problem. You need to solve it. And then all will be working.